# Why ReadWriteMany is not working on different nodes with more than one pod?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, nfs, rancher, persistent-volumes

I have a Kubernetes cluster created with **Rancher** that is conformed by 4 servers:

- Server1: Hosts the Rancher and Kubectl container.
- Server2: Node with the **etcd**, **control plane** and **worker roles**.
- Server3: Node with the **worker role**.
- Server4: Node with the **worker role**.

Additionally I have an **nfs server** to store the persistent volumes.
We create the following manifests to raise a PostgreSQL database with different replicas, these replicas are distributed in the worker Nodes.

- Persistent Volume

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  mountOptions:
    - nfsvers=4.2
  nfs:
    path: /opt/k8s-data/postgres
    server: nfs-server-ip
```

- Persistent Volume Claim

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  volumeName: postgres-pv
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

- Stateful Set

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgres
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  serviceName: "postgres-set"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:14.6-bullseye
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-pv
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

- Service

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-serv
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  ports:
    - name: postgres
      port: 5432
      nodePort: 30564
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: postgres
```

It is necessary that information can be read and written from any node and that it is available for new replicas of the pod.

Initially a single pod was raised and once the database was created, the different replicas were raised. At this point we started to insert information from each of the replicated pods to evaluate its behavior and we found that the information is not reflected in the other pods; i.e.: If I enter pod1 and insert a record in a table, it´s not reflected in pod2. If the same thing is done but this time inserting the record from pod2, then the same thing happens. If pod3 is raised, it reflects information from pod2 or information from pod3, because of that, we do not know what pod has the authority to write to the shared volume.

Another case observed is that if we bring down the cluster and raise only one pod, it may have information entered by any pod, but it never shows ALL the information entered from the pods.

Our intention is to have several replicas distributed in the nodes that can write and read information in the database and this data is always available for the existing pods and those that are raised later.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think you should use ReadWriteMany for a database like PostgreSQL.

Comment: you really dont want to share a volume between postgres instances. This will corrupt your data. Aslo using nfs to store postgres data is probably a performance nightmare.

Comment: Hi @Jonas what kind of access mode should I use?

Comment: @JuanDavid ReadWriteOnce

Comment: @JuanDavid and only a single replica, not multiple.

Comment: Hello @TheFool, thanks for your comment. What kind of volume do you think that is better to use in this case, or should I use only one replica?

Comment: @Jonas how can I get high availability with only one replica?

Comment: @JuanDavid you, cannot. For high availability you must use a distributed database with built-in replication. Use e.g. CockroachDB or e.g. CrunchyDatas Kubernetes Operator for PostgreSQL https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/v5/

Comment: classic sql databases dont have high availability. They are meant to run as single instance and sharing data between instances will corrupt your data. There are projects that can add high availability but they don't do that by sharing a volume.  As jonas mentions one example is cokroachDB which is more or less distributed postgres.

Comment: in order to persist data, with a ReadWriteOnce volume, its probably best to use a normal disk aka block storage.

Comment: @TheFool I really apreciate your help